# Worpress sort the posts

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress Tag page(tag.pgp). I have a left menu like this.

```
 <div class="well">
      <div>
          <a href="#"> ALphabatically</a> <br/>  
      </div>

       <div >
          <a href="#"> By category</a> <br/>  
      </div>


    </div>
```

I have all the posts on right side in The loop.

```
<?php
  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
    <div >
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

      <div>
        <p>Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('n.j.y'); ?> in <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p><a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  <?php }

  echo paginate_links();
?>
```

How can I sort the post alphabetically and by category by clicking on the links on left.

Comment: What do you mean, JavaScript, jQuery? To sort what kind of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
                $args_product = array(
                                            'post_type'      => 'product',
                                            'posts_per_page' => 10,
                                            'orderby'=>'title',
                                            'order'=>'ASC',
                                            'product_cat'    => $all_categories_data->slug
                                          );
                      $loop_product = new WP_Query( $args_product );

                 while ( $loop_product->have_posts() ) : $loop_product->the_post();
              ?>    
                      <div >
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
                            <div>
                                   <p>Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('n.j.y'); ?> in <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></p>
                            </div>

                             <div>
                                          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                          <p><a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                   <span><?php echo $all_categories_data->name;?></span>
                             </div>      
                     </div>             

              <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pre_get_posts action hook provided by WordPress.

Then, in your functions.php add the following code below:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query) {
    // validate
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {

        if(is_archive()) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'title'); // order posts by title
            $query->set('order', 'ASC'); // and in ascending order
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

For futher information visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts